# VUE - Mutations - Se duplican los objetos en un array cada vez que regargo el navegador

Tags: array, vue.js, vuex

Estoy añadiendo elementos a un array a través del método push(). Todo bien.
Pero cuando refresco el navegador, se añaden todos otra vez, pero no se borran los que estaban en el array antes de refrescar la página. Es decir, si obtengo 8 usuarios de la BBDD y los guardo en el array, al refrescar, se añaden los 8 otra vez, pero los 8 anteriores continúan, por lo que ahora tengo 16 repetidos. Y así va creciendo el array a medida que refresco. Creo que me explico.

Llamo a la action desde el componente, usando el ciclo de vida mounted()

```
mounted() {
    
     for(let x=2;x<=8;x++){
     this.getAllUsers(x)
}
```

A través de las Actions llamo a un método para obtener usuarios (uno a uno) de una api (le paso el id del usuario y me devuelve el usuario completo)

```
actions: {
async getAllUsers({commit}, id) {
  const resAllUsers = await api.getPilot(id)
  let a = resAllUsers.data.profile
  console.log("ACTION")
  console.log(a)
  commit('setAllUsers', a)
}
}
```

Luego hago commit en la Mutation setAllUsers:

```
mutations: {
  setAllUsers(state, payload) {
    console.log(payload)
    state.allUsers.push(payload)
  }
}
```

Y éste es el State:

```
state: {
   allUsers:  []
}
```

Los datos están llegando a la Mutation `setAllUsers()`. Pongo un ejemplo de uno de los usuarios que llegan:

```
{
  id: 5, 
  name: 'J. Miguel Ruiz', 
  biography: '', 
  flag: '46', 
  image: 'vlcsafdaf', 
  …
}
```

Comment: No lo puedo reproducir. Cada vez que recargo la página el state `allUsers` se resetea a `[]`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Alucino, te pasa lo contrario que a mí. Igualmente gracias por el intento.

Comment: Lo probé con vue2 y vuex3. No sé si es la misma versión que usas..

Comment: Sí, con vue2 está hecho